# How to reload/refresh API data everytime on clicking a navlink in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reload the API data whenever I click a navbar link.
I know the approach should be like *to reload a **state*** but I'm lost in the way to achieve it..

I'm using `<Link />` of react-router v6+ to achieve this goal.

- App.js

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

- Navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar() {
   return (
    <>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <Link to="#link">link</Link>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </>
}
```

- Data.js

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])// I'm trying to get how this data get empty every time (each and every sec or min) clicking to a navlink
//so that it gets reloaded and fetch new data

useEffect(() => {
axios.get('BASE-URL').then(() => setData(data.slice(0, 1))) //I've sliced the data to get only 1 items (total items fetched: 100 items in a array)
}, [])

//...
```

I don't know what I do to get the issue solved.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reloading API Data on Navbar Link Click in React with React Router v6+

To reload API data whenever a navbar link is clicked using React Router v6+, you can follow these steps:

1. **Create a Data Fetching Function:**

   ```js
   export const fetchData = async () => {
     try {
       const response = await axios.get('BASE-URL');
       return response.data.slice(0, 3);
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
       return [];
     }
   };
   ```

---

2. **Manage Data Using State:**

   ```js
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchData().then((newData) => setData(newData));
   }, []);
   ```

---

3. **Reload Data on Navbar Link Click:**

   ```js
   import { fetchData } from './Data';

   export default function Navbar() {
     const handleLinkClick = async () => {
       const newData = await fetchData();
       setData(newData);
     };

     return (
       <>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <Link to="#link" onClick={handleLinkClick}>
               link
             </Link>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </>
     );
   }
   ```

Now, clicking the navbar link will trigger the reload of data from the API, updating the state with fresh data. Adjust the code according to your project structure and requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it to work by doing an example

Answer (score 0):

extract that API call in the function, call that function inside a useEffect and add onClick event listener on that link that triggers the same function